# How to access Printer in Xamarin forms cross platform apps to print data?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am working on a cross platform Xamarin.Forms application in which I need to print some data content through printer.I have go through internet but i am not able to get the cross platform printer.May be i am unable to gather the related content.

So any one please suggest me an idea to implement the Print option in xamarin.forms app.

Note: I am developing the app in Android and iOS.

Comment: AFAIK there isn't any way to do this in shared code.  You would have to implement printing in the platform specific code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Jason.Can you please provide any link for reference such as samples/documentation

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/66347/printing-using-xamarin-forms